# Wrap an Image around glutWireSphere

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to wrap an image around my glutWireSphere thats I have in my OpenGL/C++ program. I am making a solar system and I have texture images that I would like to wrap around the spheres I have already drawn. I have searched Google to try and figure out how to do this but I have either found outdated tutorials or tutorials that are much more complex for what I need (at least I think).

I tried using SOIL but didn't have much luck implementing it. I was wondering if that would be the best path to go down to do what I want, or should I try another method?

Just looking for some direction here, thanks.

Comment: You can't do very much with GLUT's drawing functions (`glutWireSphere` etc) - really they're only for testing that OpenGL works.

Answer (score 0):

The specification for `glutSolidSphere` does not call for texture coordinates being generated for the generated vertices. Hence it takes some hoop jumping to get a texture image on the the sphere.

The usual approach for texturing sphere is using a 2D texture which rows and colums are mapped to longitude and latitude. This causes some weird distortion at the poles, though and doesn't look very nice in that region (this is due to a mathematical theorem that it takes at least 2 maps to cover a sphere without introducing such degenerations).

Another approach (that lends itself nicely to `glutSolidSphere`) is applying a cube-map texture and reusing the sphere vertex positions as texture coordinates. This is what I suggest: Use SOIL to load the six sides of a cube map texture and configure texture coordinate generation to use the vertex positions as texture coordinates. Most easy done in a vertex shader (simply pass the vertex position as a varying to the fragment shader where it's used for texture lookup), but can also be achieved using the old fixed function pipeline.